# Can I cancel an INSERT statement if one of the columns is duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagining I have these two `INSERT` statements, the first one was yesterday and the second one is today:

```
INSERT INTO table(id, field1, field2, field3) 
VALUES (1, "John", "Doe", "12345")

INSERT INTO table(id, field1, field2, field3) 
VALUES (1, "Mary", "May", "12345")
```

Is there a way to make these `INSERT` statements not insert rows if there is already an equal value in any row in `field3`? This means the second record wouldn't be inserted.

I have searched for this but only found cases where they use the primary key as comparison.

Comment: Add a unique index on field3..

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. And you insert _rows_, not records.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1):

you can use unique

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE (field3);
```

The UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are different.

Both the UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns.

A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Imma try it and mark as answered if everything goes right

Comment: ok, and You can directly make the field unique when you create the table @Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT with NOT EXISTS to achieve this
for example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1  as id, 'John' as field1, 'Doe' as field2, '12345' as field3) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE field3 = '12345'
);

INSERT INTO table (id, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1  as id, 'Mary' as field1, 'May' as field2, '12345' as field3) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE field3 = '12345'
);
```

Comment: Code does not meet the requirement 'not to insert records if there is already an equal value in any record on "field3"'

Comment: @P.Salmon Whatever field you want to match just add in where clause like SELECT id FROM table WHERE field3 = '1235'